# Can a signet ring be anonymous?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yehuda

In Vayeshev 38:25 Tamar sends Yehuda 's signet ring, clothing and staff back to him, and requests he recognize to whom they belong.

הִ֣וא מוּצֵ֗את וְהִ֨יא שָׁלְחָ֤ה אֶל־חָמִ֙יהָ֙ לֵאמֹ֔ר לְאִישׁ֙ אֲשֶׁר־אֵ֣לֶּה לּ֔וֹ אָנֹכִ֖י הָרָ֑ה וַתֹּ֙אמֶר֙ הַכֶּר־נָ֔א לְמִ֞י הַחֹתֶ֧מֶת וְהַפְּתִילִ֛ים וְהַמַּטֶּ֖ה הָאֵֽלֶּה׃

Rashi brings Chazzal from Sota 10b that this act somehow his Yehuda's identity until he himself confessed.

לא רצתה להלבין פניו ולומר ממך אני מעברת, אלא לאיש אשר אלה לו, אמרה אם יודה מעצמו, יודה, ואם לאו ישרפוני, ואל אלבין פניו. מכאן אמרו נוח לו לאדם שיפילוהו לכבשן האש ואל ילבין פני חברו ברבים

My question is though, isn't a signet ring something specifically used as an identifier? How can she have kept his anonymity by sending it? I would assume a walking stick and clothing were also items which could be used to identify someone, but I'm focusing on the ring as it is specifically made to be recognizable.

Comment: Yes, some rings are anonymous. Random example: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2972/hesperia.85.4.0627?seq=13#metadata_info_tab_contents. But hypothetically she could have sent it to him in a bag presuming that the messenger wouldn't have looked at it.

Comment: I don't have access to the link. I considered the bag, but it seemed strange, like someone somewhere should have mentioned that crucial point to explain Chazzal.

Comment: It probably didn't say "Yehuda Jacobson" on it, but rather had a picture of a fish or a squiggle or something. Something that he'd know and his friends whom he communicates with would know, but random people wouldn't recognize as his.

Comment: Rabbeinu Bechaye [comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.38.25.2?lang=bi) that, when speaking to the messengers, Tamar did not show them the evidence nor enumerate the specific items she held as evidence ("וְהִיא שָׁלְחָה אֶל חָמִיהָ לֵאמֹר לְאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר אֵלֶּה לּוֹ אָנֹכִי הָרָה"). She instead indicated that Yehuda should come inspect the items himself. When that didn't yield a response, she appealed to Yehuda face-to-face, enumerated the items she held as evidence, and showed them to him ("וַתֹּאמֶר הַכֶּר נָא לְמִי הַחֹתֶמֶת וְהַפְּתִילִים וְהַמַּטֶּה הָאֵלֶּה").

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a signet ring and even a signature itself can be relatively  nondescript. The Gemora Bava Basra 161B says

רַב צָיֵיר כְּווֹרָא רַבִּי חֲנִינָא
צָיֵיר חֲרוּתָא רַב חִסְדָּא סָמֶךְ רַב הוֹשַׁעְיָא עַיִן רָבָא בַּר רַב הוּנָא
מָכוּתָא

*Rav used to draw a fish to sign, Rabbi Chanina used to draw a palm branch, Rav Chisda used the letter samekh, Rav Hoshaya used  the letter ayin, and Rava bar Rav Huna used to  draw the mast of a ship as a signature.*

The Rashbam says it was well known that they signed that way. Therefore it was just good as their signature. It's still safe to say that it wasn't *universally*  known.  The messenger that Tamar used was probably someone not so familiar with Yehuda that he would have recognized the symbol on the signet ring.

Comment: This is why I used fish in my comment above

Comment: This gemara just discusses signatures not signet rings.

Comment: Presumably they didn't have signet rings. If they would have they would have been the same drawings they used to sign with.